# Call JavaScript constructor method from different file - Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript, erb

I am using the [Unobtrusive JavaScript solution for polling in a Rails application](https://gist.github.com/barelyknown/7391243), which seems to be a great solution, though I am having trouble calling the `.stop()` method from a `.js.erb` view. I want to be able to stop polling when an inline edit form is open for one of the items being refreshed by polling. I call `.stop()` from the edit.js.erb view is rendered, but it keeps polling...

unobtrusive_poller.coffee:

```
class Poller

  constructor: (@div) ->

  interval: ->
    $(@div).data("interval") ? 3000

  url: ->
    $(@div).data("url")

  start: ->
    console.log "Starting polling"
    @intervalId = setInterval(@request, @interval())

  request: =>
    # console.log "Interval: #{@interval()}"
    # console.log "URL: #{@url()}"
    console.log "Polling"
    $.ajax(
      url: @url(),
      dataType: "script").fail (data) =>
      console.log "Poll failed!" # + JSON.stringify(data)
      return

  stop: ->
    console.log "Stopping polling"
    clearInterval(@intervalId)

$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $("div[data-poll='true']").each (i, div) ->
    console.log "DIV: " + div
    new Poller(div).start()
```

edit.js.erb:

```
// Pause polling while edit form is open
console.log($('div#messages[data-poll='true']'));
new Poller($('div#messages[data-poll='true']')).stop();

// $("div[data-poll='true']").each(function(i, div) {
//   console.log("DIV: " + div);
//   return new Poller(div).stop();
// });

...
```

As I understand it, the issue is `@intervalId` is undefined.

Is this on the right track?

Any suggestions on how to make this work would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to store the object of each `div` you are initializing the polling event. You are creating new object everytime, but not storing it anywhere. You need it to store it somewhere to be able to call stop later on the object created.

> Update : storing the Id in Hash

This code create an hashmap to store all the poll event you are binding

```
window.pollHash = {}

$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $("div[data-poll='true']").each (i, div) ->
    console.log "DIV: " + div
    id = $(div).attr("id")
    pollObject = new Poller(div)
    pollObject.start()
    window.pollHash[id] = pollObject
```

And In edit.js.erb, You were again creating new object using the `new` operator. You should use the already stored objects as done above, then call stop method as shown below.

```
targetDiv = $('div#messages[data-poll='true']')
//Not sure about your target condition, replace 
// above selector as your target as per your need.
targetId = $(targetDiv).attr("id")
window.pollHash[targetId].stop()
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! That's a good suggestion, but i was not wanting to iterate through all the started `Poller` objects and stop them. I just want to be able to stop one particular `Poller`. Would you have any suggestions on how to target a particular `Poller` in the array? Thanks again!

Comment: If you could add a specific Id to each div. It would be possible. Till then its difficult to stop the target div. Even if you can append a dummy unique class it would work. Let me know if that is possible and I will update my answer.

Comment: I've updated the code, take a look. It will store all hash of the ids and then fire the stop on particular target div. If that's what you want.

Comment: This is getting close! Won't I need to change the `.stop()` method so it doesnt reference `@intervalId`?

Comment: Well the interval id is something `setInterval` returns. Its unique when you create one. So it is required when you want to stop the interval on that particular object. The code is perfect as its bounds the `intervalId` to the object and should be as it is. You have no way to keep track of which Id is generated for which div, unless you create a hash map for it. But that would defeat the whole purpose of the `stop` method, if you manually managing the intervalIds. Hope it makes sense!

Comment: Good point. Maybe a silly question; Are we sure the `pollHash` hash table is available from a js.erb view? I ran a `typeof` check on the variable `pollHash` and it came back `undefined`. Thanks again for your help so far!

Comment: Yeah, pretty nasty to declare globals in coffeescript. It wraps the variables into local scope of the file as it transpiles to javascript, unless you compile it with `-b` option. Will need to add it in window scope to access it. Updated the answer, thanks for pointing.